# TypeScript no respeta acentos

Tags: javascript, typescript

Buen día, tengo el siguiente problema, estoy realizando algunas modificaciones a un sitio web mediante compilado de typescript, funcionalidades y eventos estan funcionando correctamente, pero, por la parte de texto estoy teniendo conflicto.

Al realizar compilado la palabra **Versión** aparece como **VersiÃ³n**.

Como puedo resolver esta parte? gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto es un problema de *encoding*, el compilador de TypeScript asume por defecto que los archivos de texto que recibe tienen codificación `"utf-8"`.  Utiliza la opción del compilador `--charset` para especificar que la codificación correcta ( probablemente `"ISO-8859-1"`).

O tal vez el encoding (charset) que usas en el HTML no es el mismo que los archivos, revisa que todos estén alineados, es más fácil es cuando todo es utf-8 :)

Comment: gracias! Pude resolverlo con un "ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %" en el elemento Page de mi aspx  :)